# Not able to get the response from asp.net core controller end point in reactjs response

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core and React js.
I am not able to get the response in React from the ASP.NET controller endpoint. All code at the backend is executing from start to return response line and getting data at the return line but in the response of react js, I am not able to see the data.

I tried :

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.InputFormatters.Add(new BypassFormDataInputFormatter());
                options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                options.InputFormatters.Add(new BypassFormDataInputFormatter());
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
      }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

this is my front end :

```
getRecordsByPaging = (pagingData) => {
    debugger
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(pagingData);
    return fetch('/get-products', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: jsonData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(res => {
        return res;
    }).catch(err => err);
}
```

this is my backend:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("get-products")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomers([FromBody] req)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var response = await _productSvc.GetProducts(req);
            if (response == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return Ok(response);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }


    }
```

I do not know what am doing wrong .

I am getting at react js side :

```
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "basic"
url: "https://localhost:44384/get-products"
__proto__: Response
```

Comment: have you debugged? I think GetProducts(req); return null.

Comment: All those `return null;` statements are not good. You're smothering errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the actual response of your ajax request:

```
getRecordsByPaging = (pagingData) => {
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(pagingData);
    return fetch('/get-products', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: jsonData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(res => {
        return res;
    }).catch(err => err);
}
```

As you can see, the added line is `.then(r => r.json())` which will actually get the JSON response from your request.

You can read more about the `fetch` api at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

**Basic fetch:**

> A basic fetch request is really simple to set up. Have a look at the
>   following code:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```

> Here we are fetching a JSON file across the network and print it to
>   the console. The simplest use of fetch() takes one argument — the path
>   to the resource you want to fetch — and returns a promise containing
>   the response (a Response object).
>
> This is just an HTTP response of course, not the actual JSON. To
>   extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the json()
>   method (defined on the Body mixin, which is implemented by both the
>   Request and Response objects.)

Comment: Hey Friend , Thanks a lot for answer , Its working for me ....... You make my day ..

Thanks again !